Flutter iOS Build Error: Missing PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for Multiple Packages
I'm encountering an error during the build process of my Flutter iOS app. The error message states that the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file is missing for multiple packages, including webview_flutter_wkwebview, video_player_avfoundation, flutter_local_notifications, google_map_flutter, sqflite-sqflite, and url_launcher.
Here's the error message:
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-3.13.0/ios/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy /Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_wkwebview-3.13.0/ios/Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy: No such file or directory 
I've confirmed that the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file exists in the specified directory. Despite this, the build process seems unable to detect it.
Additionally, I have explicitly added the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file in the root directory of my iOS project.
I've tried:
Double-checking the file placement in the correct directory.
Verifying file permissions to ensure it's accessible by the build process.
Cleaning the build cache (flutter clean) and rebuilding the project.
However, the error persists.
Could someone please provide insights into why the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file might not be detected by the build process despite being present in the correct directory? Are there any additional configuration steps or considerations I might be missing?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

There is this repo, where its owner created a script that finds all missing privacy manifests and which packages have problems. It's not for sure 100% accurate but you can get an idea of what is wrong.
also, make sure you have an upgraded version of Cocoapods and if you have any plugins written, make sure they have their privacy manifest file if needed.
